# Why favorite tags' excerpts and information won't expand?

Tags: support, tags, user-interface, accessibility

When you're on the main page, your favorite tags (on the right column) won't show their excerpt or subscribing link, while the tags appearing under the questions will.
This is not narrowed to the gaming site: every stackexchange sites have the same behavior.

Is there a reason to that ?  Is it just a way to "keep it simple stupid" and avoid overloading the user interface ?

The reason I'm asking that is that I would find it convenient to manage my favorite tags' e-mail and rss subscribing directly from the home page (since they are listed there).

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the cause, but I will point out that your favorites do not have to be real tags. In particular, you can use `*` as a wildcard, as I do with "portal*" to get all portal and portal 2 related questions.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information, I wasn't aware of that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to the fact that some of those tags can include wildcards or not be real tags at all, so it is simpler to not attempt showing an excerpt overlay at all.

Plus clicking on each tag has two possible outcomes: either taking you to the full tag page or removing the tag from your favourites (if you click on the X).